# How to fetch auzre cosmos db data from azure pipeline task plugin and use it in further pipeline task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cosmosdb, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is any plugin available in azure VSTS market place to fetch cosmos db data and use it in further VSTS pipeline task.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can use [Task for Cosmos DB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=winvision-bv.winvisionbv-cosmosdb-tasks) which can do the features like

- Delete/Create/Update collections
- Import/Export data to/from Azure Cosmos DB

Some other similar extension can be [found here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=cosmos&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Pipelines&sortBy=Relevance)

[Azure Cosmos DB Emulator (which is still in public preview)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=azure-cosmosdb.emulator-public-preview) - [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-setup-ci-cd)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but am looking for a extension which can retrieve data form cosmos DB in to azure devops pipeline.